# Python requests detailed ConnectionError handling

Tags: python, exception, python-requests

I just wrote this:

```
try:
    r = requests.get('http://example.com')
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
    print(e)
```

And I got this output:

```
('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))
```

Does anyone know how could I get different types of connection errors? Like 'connection aborted', 'connection refused' and 'connection reset' from this exception and handle them?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to get the response message and then handle them. You can try this code.

```
import requests
response = requests.get("http://www.example.com")
print(response.status_code)
print(response.reason)
```

Comment: Sorry but I mean handing what I feel like sub-errors in ConnectionError class. When connection errors occur, you can't get a HTTP response code, am I right?